# Stenciljs error while project initialization

Tags: node.js, npm, stenciljs, npm-init

I am trying to create a new stenciljs project using the provided command **npm init stencil**

After running the above command, i get this error
[image]

Can someone please help me to find out what exactly is going wrong.

One observation is that after running the command, a new folder named **Rohan** is created under users directory. Here is my users's directory:
[image]

Comment: Looks like a the problem is the space in your username. What are your node/npm versions?

Comment: @Thomas True. npm version is 6.14.8 and node version is v10.18.0. Any issue related to npm or node version ?

Answer (score 1):

I was able to figure put the solution. Thanks to [Thomas](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1242317/thomas) for giving me a hint in the comment :)

The issue was related to the npm-cache path. Since i have space in the username, the cache path was not taken properly. I fixed the path by running this command(set the path for the respective folder only):

```
npm config set cache "C:\Users\Rohan~1\AppData\Roaming"
```

After this, the command **npm init stencil** will ran properly and was able to create the project.

Comment: Glad you were able to fix it, but I'm a bit surprised that npm doesn't correctly quote file paths.